# How do i integrate pubnub in mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, pubnub

i am trying to integarte pubnub(replacing socket.io withh pubnub).here below i have shown code.it is working fine for pc.but in mobile devices its not working .i am not getting error as well.any body can tel what i done wrong.
till now i have tried to replace socket with my pubnub connection

```
import PubNub from 'pubnub';
import { PubNubProvider, usePubNub } from 'pubnub-react';
 
const pubnub = new PubNub({
   publishKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
   subscribeKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
});
//leave Table when close window
const closingCode = () => {
    sendMsg("leaveTable");
    return null;
};

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
        this.receiveMsg = []
    }
    
        window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
        // Read res from service via Socket IO
        // socket.on("message", receiveMsg);
        socket.on("message", text => {
            let params = text.split("|"); //.map(p => Base64.Decode(p)); // we are not using b64 now
            let message = params.shift(); // message, eg. playerSitOut, clearTable

            this.receiveMsg.push(message);
            this.props.updateMessage({ message, params });
        });
         
      
     
   pubnub.addListener({ message: function (m) {
   const channelName = m.channel; // Channel on which the message was published
   const channelGroup = m.subscription; // Channel group or wildcard subscription match (if exists)
   const pubTT = m.timetoken; // Publish timetoken
   const msg = m.message; // Message payload
    const publisher = m.publisher; // Message publisher/  } });
        //pubnub.subscribe();
      
    }
```

Comment: You are not subscribing to any channels: `pubnub.subscribe()`.

Comment: @Craig Conover i have treied using channel also

Comment: Hard to know what's wrong without seeing valid code. Have you use code samples from these docs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/react#add-event-listeners

Comment: This is a reactjs app.  The `socket` var isn't defined when we try to run this example.  Also `sendMsg` is not defined.